# Even probabilities in sequential execution

Tags: probability

Imagine you have three actions which you execute sequentially:

doActionA

doActionB

doActionC

Additionally, there is a probability for each action to be performed (for example 33 % for each of those actions). If one of those actions is performed, the other ones will terminate.

doActionA probability 33

doActionB probability 33

doActionC probability 33

For example, if doActionA is successful, only ActionA get executed, the results of the other two actions do not matter. If ActionA fails, but ActionB has success, ActionC does not get executed. If ActionC has success, ActionA and ActionB logically also fail. If no one success, then no one gets activated.

Now my question is - as ActionA is the first and ActionB is the second in the sequence, the probability of those two are higher than ActionC, despite it says probability 33 in all three cases right? My goal is, to achieve, that all the three probabilities are even. I think because of the sequential nature of this execution, ActionA must have a smaller probability value than ActionB and ActionB must have a smaller probability value than ActionC. How can I calculate those probabilities?

Comment: It is not extremely clear what you are asking about. Perhaps showing at least the structure of the code in question would help. It seems like maybe you're asking about conditional probabilities - e.g. action A has a 33% chance of doing something, or a 67% chance of *not* doing something, which means that, with B's 33% chance of doing something, the actual probability of B happening is 67% * 33% = 22.11%, and so on...

Comment: doActionA probability 33

doActionB probability 33

doActionC probability 33

This is all the code, there is no other code. The question is about how the sequential nature of execution (execute first, then execute second and after that execute third action) does influence the probabilities. My goal is to have an even probability for all three options.

Comment: If that's the case, then your best approach is probably to use a good uniform random number generator to pick a number between 1 and 3N, inclusive, and then based on whether that number is in the range 1 to N, N+1 to 2N, or 2N+1 to 3N, perform one of the three actions. Your above approach does not result in equal probabilities, and in fact has a significant chance that none of the three actions are taken...

Comment: Unfortunately, game engine does not allow anything beside of that what I have described there. This is about database modding, so my options are very limited. Also, it is no problem that no action can be taken.

Comment: Your above approach does not result in equal probabilities  <-- I know, thats why I ask how the chance distribution has to be in order the probabilities to be equal. Obiously it is not 33 % 33 % 33 %

Comment: So if you're stuck with the existing algorithm, you probably want to set the probabilities at 33, 50 and 100% for each of the actions. In that case the first action has a 33% chance, but if it doesn't happen, then the second one will have a 50% conditional probability or 67% * 50% = 33% total probablilty. And if neither of the first two happen, then the third one always will...

Comment: If you are right, then this is the answer to my question, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @twalberg: If you're stuck with the existing algorithm, you probably want to set the probabilities at 33, 50 and 100% for each of the actions. In that case the first action has a 33% chance, but if it doesn't happen, then the second one will have a 50% conditional probability or 67% * 50% = 33% total probablilty. And if neither of the first two happen, then the third one always will...